# TypeORM Update Many to Many Column doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, graphql, typeorm

I am using typeorm with postgresql in graphql server.

I tried to update the Many to Many Column but doesn't work.

This is the User entity

```
@Entity()
class User extends BaseEntity {
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

...

  @ManyToOne((type) => Suburb, (suburb) => suburb.users, { nullable: true })
  suburb: Suburb;

  @ManyToMany((type) => Suburb, (suburb) => suburb.nearbyUsers, { nullable: true } )
  @JoinTable()
  nearbySuburbs: Suburb[];

...

}

export default User
```

And this is the Suburb entity

```
@Entity()
class Suburb extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

...

  @OneToMany((type) => User, (user) => user.suburb)
  users: User[];

  @ManyToMany((type) => User, (user) => user.nearbySuburbs)
  nearbyUsers: User[];

...

}
```

And this is the update resolver

```
const resolvers: Resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    UpdateMySuburbs: privateResolver(
      async (   _, args, { req }) => {
        const user: User = req.user;
        const { range, suburbId, nearbySuburbsIds } = args;
        try {
          const suburb = await Suburb.findOne({ id: suburbId });
          if (suburb) {
            user.suburb = suburb;
          } else {
            return {
              ok: false,
              error: "Not valid suburbId",
            };
          }
          const nearbySuburbs: Suburb[] = [];
          if (nearbySuburbsIds) {
            ...
            user.nearbySuburbs = nearbySuburbs;
          }
          user.range = range;

          await user.save();

          return {
            ok: true,
            error: null,
          };
        } catch (error) {
          return {
            ok: false,
            error: error.message,
          };
        }
      }
    ),
  },
};

export default resolvers;
```

When I send the mutation request, the server returns ok.
But there is no nearbySuburb Column in database and the nearbySuburbs weren't saved.

At the first stage I didn't use @JoinTable() for the @ManyToMany so I thought that was the problem but it wasn't.

range and suburb are saved correctly.
I think this is because that the nearbySuburb wasn't created.

Comment: req.user != entity user

Comment: @xadm I made the same resolver with Repository but it works the same way. suburb was saved but not nearbySuburbs

Comment: learn how to work with m2m relations?